# jQuery Ajax: Cannot get Array values in PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays

I have a form that have several inputs. Some of them are stored in an array. When I use the ajax function to send them to the PHP script, I can get all the values from the inputs but the array object will echo 'Array'.

```
    $('#Save').click(function(){
        var Name = $('#Name').val();
        var Type = $('select#Type selected:option').attr('value');
        var Values = new Array(1, 2, 4);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'GetValues.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {Name: Name, Type: Type, Values: Values}
        });
    });
```

PHP Script:

```
$Name = $_POST['Name'];  //echo the names.
$Type = $_POST['Type'];  //echo the type.
$Values = $_POST['Values']; // echo 'Array' ?
```

I have tried to use JSON_decode but still can't get the values from the form. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: instead of echo, try `print_r($Values)` and let me know if that prints your array or not..

Comment: `selected:option` should be `option:selected`. But you really should just use `$("#Type").val()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
echo var_dump($Values);
```

you will see the posted values in your array.

Comment: Thank you, with this I can see the array. But how can I now get the values. Should I use a foreach cycle?

Comment: it depends on what you want to do with your array (inserting into a database, ...). with foreach statement you can access your values.

Comment: I see that you are identifying your form fields with ids, if you want to seriliaze the form, you have to distribute names on your fields

Comment: Thank you very much! I added names to my fields an manage to use the serialize() function. But Can I send trough ajax the serialize variable and an an array?